# Where should I add Javascript in seattle.master page?

Tags: javascript, master-page

How Do I add this Javascript code to seattle.master page in SharePoint Designer for log off inactive user?

```
function LogOutInactive() {
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000);

    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
}

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 9) {
    window.location = "http://[your site]/_layouts/15/SignOut.aspx";
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Add it to a separate js file, and search for a .js reference in Seattle master page. Add reference to your js file just below that.

Comment: Where is core.js or menu.js so that I add the .js reference to that?

Comment: Yes, sequence matters

Answer (score 3):

The best is :

- make a copy of your seattle.master (custom_seattle.master)
- add your js reference in a scriptlink tag `<SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" Localizable="false" Name="/_layouts/JS/myFile.js" runat="server"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>` in the head of your masterpage
- put your js file referenced in the masterpage in the Layout template of SharePoint (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\JS\myfile.js`)
  Do not forget TO NOT modify standard core files. If you want to apply a patch after, the risk is your modifications will be overridden

Regards,